# Outputting multiple regressions into a LaTeX document

Tags: latex, stata, stata-macros

`Outreg2` is a community-contributed command, that helps us easily output the results of regressions run on Stata into a clean table, which can then be viewed in text, Word documents, or in LaTeX.

Using the `auto.dta` dataset, I run the following regression:

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
ssc install outreg2
gen  wtsq  = weight^2
foreach s in price headroom trunk{ 
    xi: reg `s' weight wtsq, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq using tab_base_`s'_j, keep(weight wtsq) bdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) replace
    xi: reg `s' weight wtsq foreign, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq foreign using tab_base_`s'_j, keep(weight wtsq foreign) bdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) append
    xi: reg `s' weight wtsq foreign length, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq foreign length using tab_base_`s'_j, keep(weight wtsq foreign length) bdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) append
}
```

I get output three `.tex` files named `tab_base_price_j`, `tab_base_trunk_j`, and so on. When I open the .tex files in LaTeX and run them, I obtain the regression tables in PDF in a perfect format, just as I want.
However, each of these files in LaTeX has the following format:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc} \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
*** ALL THE TABLE VALUES - DELETED from this illustration ***
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I want to create a new document (as a journal article or paper format), and I want to input one of these .tex files using 
`\input{tab_base_price_j.tex}` in LaTeX, 
I receive this error: `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

How do I output the regression tables from Stata in a way that the output `.tex` files do not have `\begin{document}`, and just start with:

```
\begin{tabular}{lccc} \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
*** ALL THE TABLE VALUES - DELETED from this illustration ***
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The `xi:` prefix is deprecated in recent versions of Stata in favour of factor variable notation. In your examples it does no harm but is pointless as no variable is flagged as  categorical (a factor variable, in other terminology).  More importantly, you should explain `outreg2` as community-contributed from SSC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `tex(fragment)` option:

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
generate  wtsq  = weight^2

foreach s in price headroom trunk { 
    regress `s' weight wtsq, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq using tab_base_`s'_j.tex, keep(weight wtsq) bdec(3) nocons tex(fragment)
    regress `s' weight wtsq foreign, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq foreign using tab_base_`s'_j.tex, keep(weight wtsq foreign) bdec(3) nocons tex(fragment)
    regress `s' weight wtsq foreign length, vce(robust)
    outreg2 weight wtsq foreign length using tab_base_`s'_j.tex, keep(weight wtsq foreign length) bdec(3) nocons tex(fragment)
}
```

You can then input these as parts of a larger document as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
... text before inclusion of table tab_base_price_j.tex ...
\input{tab_base_price_j.tex}
... text after inclusion of table tab_base_price_j.tex ...
\input{tab_base_headroom_j.tex}
... text after inclusion of table tab_base_headroom_j.tex ...
\input{tab_base_trunk_j.tex}
... text after inclusion of table tab_base_trunk_j.tex ...
\end{document}
```